# Git Merge Skipping a commit

Tags: git

I have a branch which I've merged into master.

On the branch, `git log file` shows a commit on February 9
On master, `git log file` does **not** show the commit on February 9th
On master, `git log` does show the February 9th commit

The file does not reflect the changes made on February 9th, yet `git log` shows the commit.  It appears git merged in the commit, but didn't actually apply it to the file.  What could be causing this?

Edit: I think I figured out what happened and answered below.  I cleaned up the original question for clarity.  I had originally written I thought this to be a bug with git, but I don't think that's the case anymore.  It would be nice, however, if `git log file` did show these commits to the file.  Thanks to everyone who helped, especially Borealid.

Earlier Edit: I genuinely believe this is a bug with git.  This file was never renamed, yet git believes that it was, and that is why the commit isn't being applied.  I created another branch, performed the merge, and this problem didn't occur.  I can reproduce the bug on the branches where this occurred.  I would be happy to help any git developer debug the problem with me, but I can't send you my repository.

Comment: Merge makes the branch parent of the merge. So it can't skip the commit. However I believe `git log` does *not* walk the revisions in chronological order.

Comment: Jan: The February 9th commit is not listed anywhere in the git log.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: Correction, it's listed in "git log", but not "git log certainfile" on master.  Please see my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from Dave:

> I've recreated a similar situation with the following steps:
>
> - Create a new git repository
> - Create a file with one line, add it to git and commit (commit #1)
> - Create and switch to a branch
> - Change the file in the branch, commit (commit #2)
> - Switch to master, change the file so there will be a conflict and commit (commit #3)
> - Merge branch into master, the file will be in conflict
> - Resolve the conflict by taking all the changes in master, and rejecting all the changes in the branch. Basically, the file should
>     look as it did in master.
> - Add the file and commit the changes (commit #4)
>
> Now git log will show all four commits, but git log file will only show commits #1 and #3

The reson that `git log -- file` only show commit #1 and #3 is because how git-log (default mode) walks the commit chain; when a merge commit is found and there exists a parent commit such that the selected file has the same content after the merge as in the parent commit, git-log will follow (one) such parent and reject all other parents.

In this case, since the merge conflict is resolved by only keeping changes made in master (the file will have the same content in commit #1 and commit #4) git-log will only walk the master branch.

In more details: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html (section "History Simplification")

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Since your answer doesn't make sense without the context in my answer (it references the commit numbers in my answer), I didn't mark it as accepted.  If you copy and paste my answer (and ping me), I'll be sure to mark it as such.

Comment: @Dave, I added your clarification of the problem to my answer

Comment: @Dave: you should put your answer in your question, as it isn't really an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of a file are identical before and after a change, the file was not modified by the change.

This statement is intuitively true, and because of git's object model, it's true in the repository as well.

You can inspect your `git log` and find the revision you think modified the file; if it's there in the master history, you did your merge correctly, but that changeset had no effect on the file (and so is not included in `git log -- path/to/file`).

Obviously, `git merge` is not broken - your expectations are just misaligned with what it does.

Comment: The contents are not identical.  We noticed a bug in our application because a commit containing the change didn't transfer properly with the merge.

Comment: @Dave How did you perform the merge?

Comment: From master: git merge branchname

Comment: @Dave And when you do `git log master`, is the changeset in question there in the history?

Comment: The changeset is listed with "git log" in both branch and master.  This particular changeset altered one file (certainfile).  If you type "git log certainfile | grep 89b0df62" in both master and the branch, you only get a hit in the branch.

Comment: @Dave If the changeset is in the history, it **was** applied. Did you remember the `--follow` option to `git log`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8185/discussion-between-borealid-and-dave)

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated a similar situation with the following steps:

1. Create a new git repository
2. Create a file with one line, add it to git and commit (commit #1)
3. Create and switch to a branch
4. Change the file in the branch, commit (commit #2)
5. Switch to master, change the file so there will be a conflict and commit (commit #3)
6. Merge branch into master, the file will be in conflict
7. Resolve the conflict by taking all the changes in master, and
   rejecting all the changes in the branch.  Basically, the file should
   look as it did in master.
8. Add the file and commit the changes (commit #4)

Now `git log` will show all four commits, but `git log file` will only show commits #1 and #3.